# Modifying and printing strings does not result in intended output

Tags: c, pointers

I have written two pieces of code which I intended to have identical outputs, but which, confusingly, have different outputs.

The first piece of code:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main(){
    char a[]="abc";
    char *p=&a;
    char c=++(*p);
    printf("%c,%s\n",c,p);
    return 0; 
}
```

This outputs the following:

> b,bbc

The second piece of code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char *p="abc";
    char c=++(*p); 
    printf("%c,%s\n",c,p);
    return 0; 
}
```

Which outputs:

> a,abc

What is happening in the second piece of code that prevents the first character of the string from incrementing?

Comment: It can happen in some system as the "abc" of the second code is in a memory area that couldn't be changed. In the first application the string "abc" is in the stack that always can be modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second example attempts to change a string literal which is undefined behavior. You usually get a crash for doing it but in your case it seems it was just "ignored".

> ```
> char *p="abc";
> char c=++(*p); /* Illegal to change *p. */
> ```

Standard quote:

> It  is  unspeciﬁed  whether  these  arrays  are  distinct  provided 
>   their  elements  have  the appropriate  values.  If the  program 
>   attempts  to  modify  such  an  array, the  behavior  is undeﬁned.

Comment: *p++  in this expression which operator will get the precedence

Comment: @CallYS But you used parentheses.

Comment: I have one more doubt.....
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){

char *p;

char *a="yogi";

p=a;

char c=++(*p);

printf("%c,%s,%s",c,p,a);
return 0;
}
this time the output is y,yogi,yogi
but I am expecting z,zogi,yogi.

Comment: @CallYS Still undefined behavior.